# Missing org.junit.jupiter.params from JUnit5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to add parameterized tests into my Java program. I found the examples for JUnit 5, which I do have included.

https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/

The issue is I cannot add @ParameterizedTest because the namespace is missing. Idk why or how.

The [documentation](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#api-evolution-experimental-apis) page clearly states it is in org.junit.jupiter.params, but I do not have that.

To give you an idea of my code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class SubsetPrinterTest
{
    // https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/

    static Collection<Object[]> makeSetData()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]
        {
                {1, new char[]{'1'}},
                {2, new char[]{'1', '2'}},
                {3, new char[]{'1', '2', '3'}},
                {4, new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4'}},
                {5, new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}}
        });
    }

    // This should be a parameterized test using the makeSetData.
    @Test
    void makeSet()
    {
        // Arrange
        SubsetPrinter subsetPrinter = new SubsetPrinter();

        // Act
        char[] set = SubsetPrinter.MakeSet(5);

        // Assert
        assertArrayEquals(set, new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'});
        assertEquals(set.length, 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You project class-path has to include a version of `junit-jupiter-params-xxx.jar`, like `junit-jupiter-params-5.0.0.jar` from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.0.0/

The blog post from `codefx.org` you link to says (edited to the current 5.0.0 release):

> Getting started with parameterized tests is pretty easy but before the fun can begin you have to add the following dependency to your project:
>
> ```
> Group ID: org.junit.jupiter
> Artifact ID: junit-jupiter-params
> Version: 5.0.0
> ```

Either download and add it manually, or if you're using a build tool with dependency management (Gradle, Maven, ...) configure the build script (build.gradle, pom.xml, ...) accordingly.

Find some generic samples here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples

Starting with version **5.4.0-M1** JUnit Jupiter provides an aggregator artifact that bundles all available Jupiter-defining artifacts for easy consumption. See https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-12-26-junit-jupiter-aggregator.html for details.

Comment: I have version 5 included. It was added automatically by the Intellij IDEA, but it seems to be missing this.

I will check next time I open the project. Thank you.

Comment: @Sormuras - it is a bit strange to add another dependency for that. I wonder why is this not part of jupiter-api in the first place?

Comment: Starting with version 5.4.0-M1 JUnit Jupiter provides an aggregator artifact that bundles all available Jupiter-defining artifacts. See https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-12-26-junit-jupiter-aggregator.html for details.

Comment: For gradle, add `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1'`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following dependency in pom.xml. jupiter API [Junit 5] approaches modules as plugins, each of on has to be deliberately added,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

More on: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter

Answer (score 1):

More specifically,

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It will redline, so click to update/refresh MAVEN