# Can't find ParameterizedTest and ValueSource

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I had done a simple project, trying to understand how `ParameterizedTest` and `ValueSource` works.

From the below picture it finds the import path, but it throws an error when I try to run the code:

[image]

Also the gradle file:

[image]

Here is a link to the entire [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gwDUk1Jk2Pw0heNKzoEj1m4ySs9WzJg5/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `junit-jupiter-params` in the `testCompile` source set.

`junit-jupiter-params` exports types like `@ParameterizedTest` and `@ValueSource` that are needed at compile (and run~) time.

See also: [Missing org.junit.jupiter.params from JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290916)

Starting with version 5.4.0-M1 JUnit Jupiter provides an aggregator artifact that bundles all available Jupiter-defining artifacts for easy consumption. See https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-12-26-junit-jupiter-aggregator.html for details.

Comment: Added to answer: Starting with version 5.4.0-M1 JUnit Jupiter provides an aggregator artifact that bundles all available Jupiter-defining artifacts for easy consumption. See https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-12-26-junit-jupiter-aggregator.html for details.